# Clickable div that shows a date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to click on the `<div>`, and this would trigger a date picker.

When I choose a date , it should appear inside the `.

here is the Jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dhbb57xk/)

```
<div class="date">
   <h4> Fri Nov 28 </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use a div, it isn't keyboard accessible. Use an interactive element like an `<a>` or a `<button>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [jQuery UI datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) - You can hide an input behind the `<div>` having `pointer-events:none` and manually change the text of `<div>` when date is selected, as shown below:

```js
$("#date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(date) {
    $(".date").find("h4").text(date);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.date {
  width: 49.5%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f91d04;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #777777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0px 7px #777777;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #777777;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 49.5%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="date">
  <h4> Choose Date </h4>
</div>
<input type="text" id="date" />
```

---

Not a neat way, but it's a way with less js if you must use `<div>`.

See [pointer events browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) @caniuse

Answer (score 3):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/2589/)

### HTML

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" style="visibility:hidden">
<div class="date">
   <h4> Fri Nov 28 </h4>
</div>
```

### Jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});

$('#datepicker').on('change', function() {
    $('h4').html($('#datepicker').val());
});

$('.date').on('click', function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker("show");
});
```

Comment: Do you think there is a way to get rid of the text field above the div , and click directly on the the div to trigger the date picker ?

Comment: @user3127499 is right. The `datepicker()` is tied to the `input` text field. What @user3127499 wrote is probably going to be closest implementation of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The date picker is native to jQuery UI Library.

This can be easily done by specifying a text field:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

and then including the function which calls the `datepicker()` function on the object:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Check out the complete example [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

**Edit:**

I just [modified your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhbb57xk/1/) to show a basic implementation. Note that the package `jQuery UI 1.8.16` was included. The `div` element had to be changed to an `input` element because the `datepicker()` is a type of input. If you need to extract this date from the field later you can just get the `value` of the field.

Comment: I have just made what you asked for check my answer on click on the div datepicker popsup and when you select date it is shown in the div just what you asked

Comment: Eh. The `label` element in not expressly necessary because this example is not in a form. In fact, it was pulled straight from the example in the link. Keep in mind that the question focuses on the functionality of `datepicker()`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the text field just use this CSS-trick i.e make its height and border 0/none:

CSS:

```
.date input{
    height:0px;
    border:none;  
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/2594/)**